# Nginx WordPress pretty permalinks show 404. Working only with plain permalink setting

Tags: nginx, wordpress, permalink

Tried so many tutorials but could not get it working in my local development server (CentOS 8). I can view and edit fine with plain/ugly permalinks setting. When I change to any other permalink setting, I cannot view or edit. Gives 404. But, if I set pages as draft, then I can view and edit them.

This is my site structure:

> root document folder is **/var/www** and my site is in a subfolder **/var/www/curation**

I have two separate Nginx conf files under **/etc/nginx/conf.d/** as follows:

**1. Configuration for my site where WordPress is installed and with permalinks issue:**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  repository;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    root   /var/www/curation;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    #if (!-e $request_filename) {
    #   rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
    #}

    location /curation/ {
    # Setting pretty permalinks in WordPress
    # First attempt to serve request as file ($uri)
    # or directory ($uri/). If not, redirect to
    # /index.php + query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /curation/index.php?$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    }

    location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
    }


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

**2. Configuration for my root folder (which is practically empty other than php info file and index file for testing). Sharing it for the sake of context, if it is of any help:**

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost 192.168.11.8;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    root   /var/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
 

    location / {
    # First attempt to serve reuqest as file ($uri)
    # or directory ($uri/). If not, redirect to
    # /index.php + query string
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
#        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }


    error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        #root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

I have tried suggestions from other topics but none worked. These are things I tried.

1. Disabled plugins to rule out conflicts such as cache plugins like WP
   Rocket.
2. All files and folders have correct ownership to user **nginx:nginx**
3. File and folder permissions set to 644 and 755 per WordPress recommendations
4. SELinux writeable context set on wp-config.php and wp-content folder using `sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/curation/wp-content -R`

Does the whole WordPress folder require setting SELinux context writeable, which I think is not advisable.

I am at loss. What am I doing wrong? I have been at it for last 2 days. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative solution, I **moved** the whole site to root directory `/var/www` and did minor edit to Nginx site configuration from

```
location /curation/ { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /curation/index.php?$args; 
}
```

to

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
}
```

All permalinks issues are gone and my site works well.

This is not really an answer to my original issue of **permalinks not working for site in a subdirectory**. Beats me why it did not work for a subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the site was moved from `/curation/` to `/`, but the `location` block was not changed.

The block:

```
location /curation/ { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /curation/index.php?$args; 
}
```

Should be changed to:

```
location / { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
}
```

Comment: Site was not moved and still in the subdirectory /curation. Tried anyways but did not work.

Comment: In your original question, both `root` and `location` contained the subdirectory name "curation", so one of them had to be wrong.

Comment: I removed the subdirectory name **curation** from `location` directive as suggested. Tried reversing by removing from `root` but included in `location`. Tested with fresh installation of WordPress in the subdirectory. Still same error - does not work with pretty permalink setting (works only with plain permalink setting).

Comment: @Ugyen Hey have you found a solution? Facing the same issue here mate.